# unfortunately my app has stopped (my first app in android)

Tags: java, android

this is my first .... i try to search the  problem in this website but i did not fix it

this is my code in main activity

```
package com.example.joker;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setText("why so serious ?");

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

and this fregment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.joker.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
        android:text="@string/b" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

....... i confide in your to help to fix the problem 
by the way >>>what is difference between fregment.xml and activity.xml ?

Comment: What is the exception? Post the logcat here

Comment: button belongs to fragment layout while you initialize the same in Activity leading to crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button belongs to the fragment layout

So remove the initialization of button in Activity and move it to fragment `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText("why so serious ?");
        return rootView;
 }
```

> what is difference between fregment.xml and activity.xml ?

Both are xml layouts. One is set to the activity  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and the other you inflate in fragment `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`. There is no difference.

Comment: It is works !!!...thank u so much. ..but can u explain the difference between oncreateview (layout...) and oncreateview (bundle ...) ?

Comment: @user3348242 read Activity lifecycle and fragment lifecycle. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Since you are new to android app development, I would strongly recommend to read recommendation from @Raghunandan.
The first key to get better in android development is to understand how activity management works, how it relate to fragments management